# iOS 9 Black Launch Screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios9

I've been developing my app and was running fine until iOS8. However, today after updating my phone to iOS9, I saw that the launch screen of my app became black. The same issue happened to some other apps as well (Anyone else can also see this in on a device running iOS 9).

Any idea why this may be the case? How can I fix this?

Comment: Who marked this issue as 'off topic'? This is not merely an iOS 9 issue, but could be an issue related to a transparent PNG ( having alpha) in the launch screen XIB!

Comment: Ducky, yeah I agree - I was surprised too. It appears that many developers are facing the same issue - my solution was to recompile the app in xcode 7.

Comment: I hope that people spend more time trying to figure out the actual problem that the help seeker asked, rather than just immediately down vote because they don't fully understand the issue...

Comment: This is not off-topic.  Here is how I solved this in Xamarin.iOS.  My app is Portrait only and I had two launch images (768x1004 and 1536x2008) in the Info.plist editor.  To fix it, I clicked on "Migrate to Asset Catalog" and then double clicked on the "Content.json" inside "Resources/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchImage" to add the iPad portrait images for icon5,6 and 7,8 (768x1024 and 1536x2048).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution: downloaded xcode 7, updated my code to swift 2, recompiled the app and problem solved.

Comment: When you say "_updated my code to swift 2_" does that mean change the actual code, or "tell xcode to treat this as swift 2"? In case of the 2nd option - could you add how this is done?

Comment: sorry for late reply. I simply opened my app in xcode 7 and followed the prompts to convert the code to swift 2.

Answer (score 2):

I has same problem.
and in my case was fixed do a re-install from the App Store.

Comment: Reinstall of what? Xcode?

Comment: Not sure what you mean re-install from App Store - are you talking about the app? It's a new app in development and is not on the app store yet. Or are you talking about xcode?

Comment: Sorry, I did reinstall the app. Twitter and Chrome Browser has same problem on iOS 9 too.

Comment: Deleting the app from my phone and reinstalling from the App Store worked for me too.  This issue seems to affect many apps.