# Black screen when launching the app on device since XCode7 update

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7, launchimage

I've updated XCode7 and like everyone, i have to amend a part of my code to be compliant with Swift2.

But i have a problem, when i m testing the app on the simulator i have no problem. But when i m trying directly on my real device (Iphone 5S IOS9), a black screen displays just with the level of the battery.

I have tried during 3 days to find something on stackoverflow, but nothing seems working.

This topic seems to be the same problem, but doen't work actually. [IOS 7 launch image, displaying black screen on device ONLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460911/ios-7-launch-image-displaying-black-screen-on-device-only)

I' ve followed the topic [iOS 9 Black Launch Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621237/ios-9-black-launch-screen) but it doesn't bring any correct solution

Any idea, or help will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 9 Black Launch Screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621237/ios-9-black-launch-screen)

Comment: This topic was closed and the solutions didnt work. :(

Comment: Try to reboot your device. I was also facing the same issue, after rebooting my device its working properly.

Comment: Just try and now still black screen but i dont see battery anymore . :(

Comment: Many had already raised this issue in Apple developer forum and there might new update soon to resolve this issue.
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7226876?start=45&tstart=0 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/54122#54122

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its worked for me:

You can solve this problem using following steps :

1. First select root level of project and then go in **General tab** and Find that below blocks.
2. By default, in "**Launch images Source**" it shows "**Use assets catalogs**", click on it
3. It will ask you to "**Migrate launch images to an asset catalog**", simply click on "**migrate"**.
4. Now, In same block in **"Launch Screen file"**, remove default launch screen xib or storyboard. because we don't need to specify it. Just put blank on there.
5. Now it shows, "**Brand Assets**" in ***launch Images Source"**, just click on right side arrow of it and set all your app launch screen assets with specific naming scheme.
6. Press "**alt + cmd + shift + k**". It will clean build folder of your application.
7. Now, build and run your app in device.

Comment: many thanks Pavan, do you know why this problem was occured ?

Answer (score 0):

When your app connects to an Webserver or to a domain with `localhost` or non `https` means `http` , than post below into your `info.plist`:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
<dict>  
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>  
    <dict>  
        <key>127.0.0.1</key>  
        <dict>  
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>  
            <true/>  
        </dict>  
        <key>localhost</key>  
        <dict>  
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>  
            <true/>  
        </dict>  
    </dict>  
</dict>
```

This let the app make an exception to use Urls without SSL / https.