# My iOS objective-C app shows black screen when launch using Xcode 7 and above

Tags: ios, objective-c

My iOS objective-C app shows black screen when launch using Xcode 7 and above. It works fine using Xcode 6.1.1. This happens only on device, works perfectly for simulators.

We are doing
[self.window setRootViewController:viewController];
viewcontroller is UINavigationController connected in XIB (IBOutlet) and has root view controller as our login screen.
And if I do this programmatically, by initialising Login Screen and view controller it crashes saying Could not load nib LoginScreen.

Thanks in Advance! 
Ganesh

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32837685/3708242

Comment: For My app Launch image is loading correctly. After Showing launch image Its not loading Login Screen, shows only blank screen.

Comment: Try changing the background color of your rootView and see if it still shows black or the new color.

Comment: Also, put a breakpoint where you set the rootViewController and make sure your viewController is set correctly. I suspect it is not.

Comment: Tried changing color.  No effect, it shows black screen only :( ...

Comment: As I mentioned, viewController  is outlet for UINavigationController and its root view controller is set in XIB itself.

Comment: This is getting weirder and weirder... I deleted my login xibs and added them again, now i m able to see Login screen. But after that when it goes home screen it is showing Black screen for all of the controllers in Tab Bar. Looks like xcode 7 having trouble with load these old xibs. I cannot do this for each of the xibs. Any solution to this ? :(...

Comment: Any solution to this :( ...